# Change the Application Name of SSMS

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to change Application Name that SSMS (Sql server Management Studio) uses when making a connection? We need to alter it so we can distinguish different instances.
I believe this is not an option in the settings.

Kind Regards, Tom

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the connection dialog, go to Options, select the Additional Connection Parameters tab and write:

```
Application Name=<YOUR APP NAME>
```

Comment: I was using sql server 2005 SSMS and the tab "Additional Connection Parameters" is not available. It seems to be only available starting from 2008.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/app-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for `APP_NAME()`:

> To set an application name in Management Studio, click Options in the Connect to Database Engine dialog box. On the Additional Connection Parameters tab, provide an app attribute in the format `;app='application_name'`

However i've only managed to get this to work on a fresh session of management studio, ie. close the program and add the parameter on the first connection to said database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called an Alias. See [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1620/how-to-setup-and-use-a-sql-server-alias/) for instructions on how to set one up.

Comment: I tried the alias but you cannot alter the Application Name used to connect

Comment: I think I misunderstood the original question. What provider are you using in your connection string?

Comment: You might be able to do this in your connection string:

`Data Source=SERVER1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SomeDb;Integrated Security=True;Application Name=Test`

Comment: It's SSMS that I want to register with a different Application Name. I don't directly control its connection string.

Comment: Then no, I don't think it's possible either.