# Change the application name of sqlcmd

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I am using sqlcmd command line to connect to a database. I want to change the application name so that I can have multiple processes using sqlcmd, and be able to differentiate these processes from the server side. I know in SQL Server Management Studio I could do this ([Change the Application Name of SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614659/change-the-application-name-of-ssms)), but how can I do this in command line?

I checked the `sqlcmd -?`, but didn't find any useful parameter. There is another command line tool bcp, but I don't find any useful info there either.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to change the application name of `sqlcmd`, if I am honest. But you can't provide connection strings to `sqlcmd`, it builds its own based on the values you pass for its switches. If you want to have details of different applications connecting to your instance, you should be creating your own applications and supplying the `APPLICATION NAME` property in their connection string.

Comment: Hi @Larnu thank you for the reply. If you know any other way to customize connection string from command line, that would be useful too. I tried to connect to odbc from command line, but no luck either. It seems I can only use a Python/C# application that connects with a driver (like odbc) and then specify the connection string in the application.

Answer (score 1):

The flag -H can be used to set "workstation_name".
It's is not the application name, but can serve the same purpose.
Use `SELECT HOST_NAME()` to get the value.